# Reading MS Office documents in webkit browsers

Tags: php, html, excel, webkit, ms-word

Other than displaying browser supported files such as images, videos, txt files, pdfs etc.. I'd like to also build a module that displays xls and doc, docx, dot files as well.

For excel files, I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/) php library that looks very promising.  Similarly, I've been searching for a method that supports Word documents.  Is there currently a library or API out there that can handle this?  I haven't been able to find anything so far.

Thanks!

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ / http://phpword.codeplex.com/ / http://phppowerpoint.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://libopc.codeplex.com/